# Function in ObservableCounter is not fired if method is run from NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, open-telemetry

I have simple class `A` with ObservableCounter as field. In `Startup` I register instance of another class `B` with field of `A` type. If I run my application as webApp (via Visual Studio 2022) everything works perfectly, and function insede ObservableCounter is called.
I also wrote some unit tests in NUnit and there's a big issue, because in this case after I call code with my ObservableCounter function inside is never called!
Below is schema of my code:

```
public class Startup
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          //some code
          //register of my controller
          services.AddSingleton(new B());
        }
}

public class B
{
  private A aInstance;

  public B()
  {
   this.aInstance = new A();
  }

   public List<int> Get()
   {
     return this.aInstance.GetAll();
   }

   public void Add(int x)
   {
     this.aInstance.Add(x);
   }
}

public class A()
{
   private Meter meter;
   private List<int> myField;

   public A(){
   this.myField = new List<int>();

   this.meter = new Meter("ourMeter");
            var observableCounter = this.meter.CreateObservableCounter<int>("AddCounter", () =>
            {
                return myField.Count(); //function to call
            }
            );
}
   public void Add(int x)
   {
     this.myField.Add(x);
   }

   public List<int> GetAll()
   {
     return this.myField.GetAll(); 
   }
}
```

There is my NUnit Test where function in observableCounter is not called:

```
[TestFixture]
public TestClass
{

 [Test]
 public void MyTest()
 {

  var aInstance = new A(); // function inside observableCounter is not called
  //the rest of my test
 }
}
```